# email exist or not working in gmail only not in other domains

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

i am trying to check email exist or not but its giving correct result while i am checking gmail and on other domain it's giving available for all email 
is there any php class which can used for all domain names please suggest me.

```js
<?php  
   
 /** 
 * Validate Email Addresses Via SMTP 
 * This queries the SMTP server to see if the email address is accepted. 
 * @copyright http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/2.0/ - Please keep this comment intact 
 * @author gabe@fijiwebdesign.com 
 * @contributers adnan@barakatdesigns.net 
 * @version 0.1a 
 */  
class SMTP_validateEmail {  
  
 /** 
  * PHP Socket resource to remote MTA 
  * @var resource $sock  
  */  
 var $sock;  
  
 /** 
  * Current User being validated 
  */  
 var $user;  
 /** 
  * Current domain where user is being validated 
  */  
 var $domain;  
 /** 
  * List of domains to validate users on 
  */  
 var $domains;  
 /** 
  * SMTP Port 
  */  
 var $port = 25;  
 /** 
  * Maximum Connection Time to an MTA  
  */  
 var $max_conn_time = 30;  
 /** 
  * Maximum time to read from socket 
  */  
 var $max_read_time = 5;  
   
 /** 
  * username of sender 
  */  
 var $from_user = 'user';  
 /** 
  * Host Name of sender 
  */  
 var $from_domain = 'localhost';  
   
 /** 
  * Nameservers to use when make DNS query for MX entries 
  * @var Array $nameservers  
  */  
 var $nameservers = array(  
 '192.168.0.1'  
);  
   
 var $debug = false;  
  
 /** 
  * Initializes the Class 
  * @return SMTP_validateEmail Instance 
  * @param $email Array[optional] List of Emails to Validate 
  * @param $sender String[optional] Email of validator 
  */  
 function SMTP_validateEmail($emails = false, $sender = false) {  
  if ($emails) {  
   $this->setEmails($emails);  
  }  
  if ($sender) {  
   $this->setSenderEmail($sender);  
  }  
 }  
   
 function _parseEmail($email) {  
  $parts = explode('@', $email);  
 $domain = array_pop($parts);  
 $user= implode('@', $parts);  
 return array($user, $domain);  
 }  
   
 /** 
  * Set the Emails to validate 
  * @param $emails Array List of Emails 
  */  
 function setEmails($emails) {  
  foreach($emails as $email) {  
  list($user, $domain) = $this->_parseEmail($email);  
  if (!isset($this->domains[$domain])) {  
    $this->domains[$domain] = array();  
  }  
  $this->domains[$domain][] = $user;  
 }  
 }  
   
 /** 
  * Set the Email of the sender/validator 
  * @param $email String 
  */  
 function setSenderEmail($email) {  
 $parts = $this->_parseEmail($email);  
 $this->from_user = $parts[0];  
 $this->from_domain = $parts[1];  
 }  
   
 /** 
 * Validate Email Addresses 
 * @param String $emails Emails to validate (recipient emails) 
 * @param String $sender Sender's Email 
 * @return Array Associative List of Emails and their validation results 
 */  
 function validate($emails = false, $sender = false) {  
    
  $results = array();  
  
  if ($emails) {  
   $this->setEmails($emails);  
  }  
  if ($sender) {  
   $this->setSenderEmail($sender);  
  }  
  
  // query the MTAs on each Domain  
  foreach($this->domains as $domain=>$users) {  
     
  $mxs = array();  
    
   // retrieve SMTP Server via MX query on domain  
   list($hosts, $mxweights) = $this->queryMX($domain);  
  
   // retrieve MX priorities  
   for($n=0; $n < count($hosts); $n++){  
    $mxs[$hosts[$n]] = $mxweights[$n];  
   }  
   asort($mxs);  
   
   // last fallback is the original domain  
   array_push($mxs, $this->domain);  
     
   $this->debug(print_r($mxs, 1));  
     
   $timeout = $this->max_conn_time/(count($hosts)>0 ? count($hosts) : 1);  
      
   // try each host  
   while(list($host) = each($mxs)) {  
    // connect to SMTP server  
    $this->debug("try $host:$this->port\n");  
    if ($this->sock = fsockopen($host, $this->port, $errno, $errstr, (float) $timeout)) {  
     stream_set_timeout($this->sock, $this->max_read_time);  
     break;  
    }  
   }  
    
   // did we get a TCP socket  
   if ($this->sock) {  
    $reply = fread($this->sock, 2082);  
    $this->debug("<<<\n$reply");  
      
    preg_match('/^([0-9]{3})/ims', $reply, $matches);  
    $code = isset($matches[1]) ? $matches[1] : '';  
   
    if($code != '220') {  
     // MTA gave an error...  
     foreach($users as $user) {  
      $results[$user.'@'.$domain] = false;  
  }  
  continue;  
    }  
  
    // say helo  
    $this->send("HELO ".$this->from_domain);  
    // tell of sender  
    $this->send("MAIL FROM: <".$this->from_user.'@'.$this->from_domain.">");  
      
    // ask for each recepient on this domain  
    foreach($users as $user) {  
      
     // ask of recepient  
     $reply = $this->send("RCPT TO: <".$user.'@'.$domain.">");  
       
      // get code and msg from response  
     preg_match('/^([0-9]{3}) /ims', $reply, $matches);  
     $code = isset($matches[1]) ? $matches[1] : '';  
    
     if ($code == '250') {  
      // you received 250 so the email address was accepted  
      $results[$user.'@'.$domain] = true;  
     } elseif ($code == '451' || $code == '452') {  
   // you received 451 so the email address was greylisted (or some temporary error occured on the MTA) - so assume is ok  
   $results[$user.'@'.$domain] = true;  
     } else {  
      $results[$user.'@'.$domain] = false;  
     }  
      
    }  
      
    // quit  
    $this->send("quit");  
    // close socket  
    fclose($this->sock);  
     
   }  
  }  
 return $results;  
 }  
  
  
 function send($msg) {  
  fwrite($this->sock, $msg."\r\n");  
  
  $reply = fread($this->sock, 2082);  
  
  $this->debug(">>>\n$msg\n");  
  $this->debug("<<<\n$reply");  
    
  return $reply;  
 }  
   
 /** 
  * Query DNS server for MX entries 
  * @return  
  */  
 function queryMX($domain) {  
  $hosts = array();  
 $mxweights = array();  
  if (function_exists('getmxrr')) {  
   getmxrr($domain, $hosts, $mxweights);  
  } else {  
   // windows, we need Net_DNS  
  require_once 'Net/DNS.php';  
  
  $resolver = new Net_DNS_Resolver();  
  $resolver->debug = $this->debug;  
  // nameservers to query  
  $resolver->nameservers = $this->nameservers;  
  $resp = $resolver->query($domain, 'MX');  
  if ($resp) {  
   foreach($resp->answer as $answer) {  
    $hosts[] = $answer->exchange;  
    $mxweights[] = $answer->preference;  
   }  
  }  
    
  }  
 return array($hosts, $mxweights);  
 }  
   
 /** 
  * Simple function to replicate PHP 5 behaviour. http://php.net/microtime 
  */  
 function microtime_float() {  
  list($usec, $sec) = explode(" ", microtime());  
  return ((float)$usec + (float)$sec);  
 }  
  
 function debug($str) {  
  if ($this->debug) {  
   echo htmlentities($str);  
  }  
 }  
  
}  
  
   
?>
```

```html
<?php

require_once("smtpvalidateclass.php");

// the email to validate  
$emails = array('infodhcjkdshjkhdksrahul@yahoo.com');  
// an optional sender  
$sender = 'user@example.com';  
// instantiate the class  
$SMTP_Valid = new SMTP_validateEmail();  
// do the validation  
$result = $SMTP_Valid->validate($emails, $sender);  
// view results  
var_dump($result);  
echo ' is '.($result ? 'valid' : 'invalid')."\n";  
  
// send email?   
if ($result) {  
  //mail(...);  
}

?>
```

Comment: @TomUdding it's working on gmail but not on others like yahoo and other domains

Comment: Could you rephrase your question (for others)? It is quite hard to understand what works and what doesn't work.

Comment: @TomUdding if i am validating working_mailid@gmail.com and non_working_mailid@gmail.com it works well , but when i am using working_mailid@freemail.it and non_working_mailid@@freemail.it or non_working_mailid@yahoo.com ..it's giving wrong result

Comment: You could base something on the SMTP class provided with PHPMailer. There's [an example that checks connections](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/smtp_check.phps) included with it, and it should not be too hard to extend that to check addresses. Be aware though that this kind of checking is not that effective - many hosts will start blocking you if you if you do this frequently, and many others will accept messages only to send you bounces later. The only way to tell for sure is to really send a message.